# My First Circuit Diagram - How to improve it

Tags: microcontroller, circuit-design

I started taking more of an interest in micro-controllers and electronics last year, I started to design a circuit (which I hoped to have created as a custom PCB - Though I don't know how to go about this and the online choices are baffling to newbies).

Anyway since I have now got a spare hour most days, I'd like to continue where I left off...

So I created the attached circuit diagram and would like to ask the experienced people to please help me iron out issues in my design.

Not having a background in electronics, I'm sure my design is missing bits and pieces, So please help me by pointing the issues out so that I can amend my diagram before starting to look at custom PCB design.

I'm still learning too so please be gentle.

Thank You.

Diagram
[image]

## UPDATE

Sorry, I have been notified that I am asking opinions?
What I mean to ask is if the circuit diagram when created in hardware (soldered) will work or not.

Or If I am missing capacitors or resistors as per standard recommended design patterns.

Thank You

## UPDATE II

This is the sample diagram from the propeller datasheet.
[image]

## UPDATE III

Moved Caps around and added new one's where they were needed.
[image]

## UPDATE IV

[image]

Comment: seems you're asking for opinions (there's a rule against that), there's  too many grounds on pin 20, 5V apparently coming from nowhere, also vector images are preferred for schematics.

Comment: @Jasen Pin 20 on the Propeller MCU goes to Vertical Sync (VS) on the connector which will be connected to a D Plug to the VGA monitor. I say this because you lost me a bit.

Comment: oops, I meant pin 9

Comment: @Jasen, Thank You, I've added the reference datasheet, So I have made a mistake? I'm just going to cross check the wiring in it again.

Comment: @Jasen, Okay I see what you mean now,, Thank You. SO I need to take one of the earthing points of the wire line that goes out from Pin9 (Vss) on the propeller chip. Well thats 1 thing I know now.  Thanks. Anything else jump out at you?

Comment: You need power supply bypass capacitors between supply and ground on every IC, and a couple of electrolytics as well.

Comment: @Peter Bennett - next to some of the power connectors for each module... there are caps, should I remove them from there and place them directly next to each of the IC's instead? Thank You

Comment: When you lay out the board, you should place 0.1 uF capacitors as close as practical to the power and ground pins of each IC - where they are shown on the schematic is not particularly relevant, but showing them near the ICs may remind you to put them there on the board.  You probably also need a couple of small caps (15 pF or so) from each side of the crystals to ground.

Comment: @Peter Bennett - I have added caps where they missing, and moved others closer to the IC's. About the 15pf caps? So I should add 1 fro 5Mhz crystal to ground? Like from Pin30 to Pin29 on Propeller MCU?

Comment: I expect to see small caps from each side of a crystal to ground - on the P8X32, from pin 30 ro ground, and pin 31 to ground - but check the datasheet for that part for recommendations.  I haven't dealt with 32 KHz crystals, so don't know if caps are also required there - check the datasheet for that chip.

Comment: @Peter Bennet - Thank You, after re-reading the manual I see no extra caps/resistors are required (updated above in Update IV)

Comment: @Zeddy You should add a suitable debouncing network (a simple RC circuit with the R pulled up to Vdd and a cap connected across the switch) to ensure that the controller doesn't see spurious reset pulses. The circuit will give you the added benefit of a power-on reset.

Comment: @Avin, Thank you - I take it r/c network means resistor /capacitor? gosh this is a little out of my league I think I need a professional or amatuer to do the soldering and design for me

Comment: @Zeddy Yes, I meant a resistor-capacitor network only. You could search for RC debouncing circuit in google for some ideas.

Comment: @Zeddy don't be too intimidated by soldering.  With just a good fine tip iron, sponge, solder and flux plus some twezzers and perhaps a helping hands(The name of a tool, not people hands), you can reasonably solder pretty much anything throughhole and many SM devices with bare contacts on the sides.  Prep work and patience will carry you if you research how to solder correctly.  The dip components you're working with shouldn't be bad to work with.